# Rails 3 does not see my class in "lib" directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've placed the file `rack_app.rb` with simple Rack application in the `lib` directory:

```
class RackApp
  def call env
    [200, {}, 'Hello']
  end
end
```

Then I've added this route:

```
match 'rack' => RackApp
```

And when I try to launch the rails server I get the following error:

`config/routes.rb:65: uninitialized constant RackApp (NameError)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rails 3 has no more autoloading by default. So you need require your file

```
require 'lib/rack_app.rb'
```

Or come back the autoloading in application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib )
```

Comment: By the way, you can do `require 'rack_app'` as well since "lib" directory is in the load path.

Answer (score 0):

Include `require 'email_format_validator'` in the model.